# How to test a javax.validator on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, junit

This is my model:

```
public class Input implements Serializable, Persistable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Long value;

    @NotNull
    private String description;
```

And on my service because of a requirement I am supposed to check if the object is valid, hence I have this method :

```
@Service
public class Service {
    
    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

public boolean isValid(final Input i) {
          Set<ConstraintViolation<input>> violations = validator.validate(i); 
          if (violations.isEmpty()) {
              return true; 
              }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

however when I run the below test it gives me false, actually the method returns false all the time.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExerciseServiceTest {
    
    @MockBean
    Service Service;    
    
    @Test
    public void testIfObjectIsValid() {
        Input i = new Input();
        i.setDescription("s");
        i.setValue(15L);
        boolean result = service.isValid(e);
        assertThat(result).isTrue();
    }
```

any sort of hint would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't calling your real service as you have wired it in with @MockBean. You need to wire it in with @Autowired or @Resource to get the real bean.

Comment: Trying to do that gives a "Failed to load application Context" error, with the following explanation : "No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available"

Comment: @kevvvvv Then you don't have the validation starter included.

Comment: yeap, that solved it. Thanks to both of you!